spring boot app with rabbitmq queue connection refused while running by dockercompose
services:

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: mydatabase
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    networks:
      - exchange

  rabbit:
    container_name: rabbit
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    networks:
      - exchange

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@example.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - exchange

  currency-provider:
    build:
      context: C:/Users/user/Desktop/exchange_api2/newApi/currency-provider
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbit
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_PORT: 5672
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_USERNAME: guest
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_PASSWORD: guest
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
    networks:
      - exchange

i try connect currency-provider to rabbit, dockercompose file looks ok, also dockerfile in springboot app :
FROM openjdk:17-alpine

ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar

COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"] 

looks ok. But when i run dockercompose im having:
2024-07-11T09:42:00.696Z  INFO 1 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2024-07-11T09:42:00.739304717Z 2024-07-11T09:42:00.719Z ERROR 1 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
2024-07-11T09:42:00.739371521Z 
2024-07-11T09:42:00.739382622Z org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

logs. Shouldnt it try to connect to rabbit:5672 intead if localhost:5672, as i set in enviroment in dockercompose?
Here is also application.yml of springboot exchange-provider app
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest

rabbit:
  rates-queue-name: rates_queue


ok, i have been starting dockercompose by dockercompose up, instead of dockercompose build command. thats why the environment was not taken into account.
